# ip6tables-restore is failing to remove a rule

Tags: iptables, ip6tables

I want to block all ipv6 traffic, I have the following rules:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

I don't want to reject, I want to drop it all.

I used this file to set my rules :

```
*filter
-F
-X
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-D INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
-D OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
COMMIT
```

but this line is failing when I try `ip6tables-restore`

```
-D INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
```

I can delete the rule by command line but i don't know why I can't using a file.

[EDIT]
I need to use a custom file to set my rules cause in my system, the script starting the ip6tables is in a read only partition and it sets some rules by default and then it add my custom file using `ip6tables-restore --noflush`

Thanks.

Comment: If you wanna drop, then use `-j DROP`.

Comment: I want to drop but this rule of reject is a rule set by default and I can't change it so I need to remove it.